# How can I set-up a domain in Azure and use Exchange Server services there?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm currently raising a startup company that's using an ISP's services. All we have at this time is IMAP for e-mail. And we're using JIRA/Confluence.

I want to migrate us to a comprehensive infrastructure, using domain accounts for our Windows 10x64 machines, e-mails, shared calendars, shared contacts (i.e. Exchange Server features), Azure DevOps, MS Teams, SharePoint etc.

I did some research, but I couldn't find any information explaining on how to do that, particularly regarding using Outlook 2019 with Azure. When it's about Azure AD, I only find information on how to synchronize a local domain to Azure, but no information on how to easily utilize Azure as a replacement for a domain controller.

As a start, I would need to know what to do in order to create a domain on Azure (i.e. using Azure as a domain controller), migrate our domain name to Azure AD and to get Exchange Server features running in Azure, so we can use Outlook 2019 on their machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating a domain in Azure with a DC VM in Azure and running Exchange Server in an Azure VM, you could simply sign up for Office 365 for email, Sharepoint, OneDrive, Teams, etc. and use Azure AD Join to join your Windows 10 client computers to Azure AD and join a Windows Server 2019 VM running in Azure to Azure AD.

Comment: Thank you very much! ... From what you wrote, will I still need to run a Server 2019 VM as a DC? I would have wished to get rid of that. ... And, with Office 365, will I be able to use MS Outlook 2019 local application with Office 365 and use a shared calendar, contacts etc.? (I prefer local applications over web interfaces.)

Comment: Do you need a DC? That depends on your use case. If you only need to manage Windows 10 devices, then you can use Intune (with the appropriate Office 365 subscription). If you need more management capabilities than Intune provides then you might need a DC. As for using Office 2019 on your computers to access Office 365 services (Exchange, Sharepoint, etc.), yes you can use Office 2019. You can also use the Office apps included with your subscription (with the appropriate Office 365 subscription).

Comment: Very helpful answer again! If we subscribe to Office 365 and migrate our domain, will we be able to work with Azure DevOps and Azure in general with these domain accounts, too?

Comment: In general, yes. Office 365 and Azure share the same Azure AD instance.